# Audio Metadata Plugin on PhoneGap not working on IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I am successfully using the Audio Metadata Plugin on Android. But when trying to build for IOS it's returning the below error;

The following 3rd-party plugin is causing the build to fail and may need to be updated to a newer version: com.surfernetwork.audiometadata

```
<gap:plugin name="com.surfernetwork.audiometadata" source="npm"/>
```

I have tried using multiple phonegap-versions but none of them worked.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not your side of things, is the plug in side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this plugin to a test app on my end and uploaded it to PhoneGap Build. The issue is definitely the plugin. Reviewing the generated log, I found:

/tmp/gimlet/2590426/project/MyExampleQRReader/Plugins/com.surfernetwork.audiometadata/IcyStreamMeta.m:66:42: error: no visible @interface for 'NSURLResponse' declares the selector 'allHeaderFields'
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];

Since this is a custom plugin issue, you can [download it from NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.surfernetwork.audiometadata) and try to fix the issue yourself, or better yet, [contact the author](https://www.npmjs.com/~shahidj) for support.